# How to notify main thread on exceptions occuring in scheduledExecutor task threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task within a [`ScheduledExecutor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) running on a regular interval. If there are particular exceptions which I want to boil up to the main thread, what is a clean way to do this? There doesn't seem to be a way to catch exceptions from a `ScheduledFuture`, and if I simply attempt to throw a `RuntimeException` on a scheduled task, that task will cease and never be run again by the `ScheduledExecutor`.

Currently, I just have a public static member in the main thread that I use to receive events from scheduled tasks but this hardly seems ideal. Any recommended reading for me to look at or any ideas?

Edit: Apologies, allow me to expand on this with an example:

```
public class TestScheduledFuture {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService taskScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TestScheduledTask(),2,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

My goal here is to simply throw a RuntimeException() in main() if I ever encounter a RuntimeException within TestScheduledTask().

Right now, I have a public static concurrentQueue in the main class which I add exceptions into from the scheduled threads. Perioidically in main() I simply poll the queue and react to any exceptions in the queue. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: related: [Inter thread communication in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170520/inter-thread-communication-in-java)

Comment: How are you submitting tasks to the scheduler?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "main thread".  What sort of application is this?

Comment: what are you going to do with the exceptions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the exceptions back to another thread via a queue seems a perfectly reasonable thing to do tbh. An alternative is, as insighter says, use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler` as otherwise the exception just goes unhandled by the `ExecutorService`. To use this you need need to supply a `ThreadFactory` when you create it, something like this

```
class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private final ThreadFactory DEFAULT_THREAD_FACTORY = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = DEFAULT_THREAD_FACTORY.newThread(r);
        thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler());
        return thread;
    }
};


class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        // give this a reference to main so it can call some method to pass e and t back 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler
```

Comment: That's not especially helpful. Perhaps you'd care to elaborate?