# Dialog betwen Velocity engine and java task

Tags: java, parsing, templates, dialog, velocity

I would like to parse Velocity templates using Apache [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.2/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/Velocity.html) runtime engine line by line with java. I mean, I would like evaluate each one of the lines of the velocity script, getting the answer for that single line, if any, as an input to another task. This other task will process the input and will send it's output to the Velocity script that may use it or not.

How can I stablish this runtime dialog betwen the Velocity engine and the other task?

Answer (score 0):

It is a producer-consumer problem, and you can achieve that with Threads interaction.

Refer these for more info:

[Java Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

[Threads Interaction/Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170520/inter-thread-communication-in-java)

[Producer Consumer Problem](http://java67.blogspot.com/2012/12/producer-consumer-problem-with-wait-and-notify-example.html)