# How to send the message from one thread to MainThread in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to know how we can send the message from one thread to the main thread in kotlin. ps: Not on android. I don't want any android platform specific answer.

I've tried this in android platform as below

```
    private val uiThreadHandler = object : Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
            (msg.obj as () -> Unit)()
        }
    }
```

And using this as

```
uiThreadHandler.obtainMessage(0, block).sendToTarget()
```

I want to achieve this on plain kotlin. How to achieve this thread communication in kotlin ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inter thread communication in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170520/inter-thread-communication-in-java)

Comment: @Moira I am sending a block of code. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way in Kotlin is to use Coroutines and suspend functions

```
class YourClass : CoroutineScope {

    // context for main thread
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + Job()

    fun toDoSmth() {
        launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
              // task(1) do smth in another thread
            }
              // do smth in main thread after task(1) is finished
        }
    }
}
```

Read also about Dispatchers

Answer (score 0):

Message handling is strictly connected with *Android*. But you actually don't want to send a message to the handler. You'd actually only run code on that thread. So instead of using the messages like you're doing, you should just call [`post(Runnable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)):

```
val uiThreadHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

uiThreadHandler.post {
    ...
}
```

To abstract this even further, you could use [*Kotlin Coroutines*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) with the *Android* extension for `Dispatchers.Main`:

```
GlobalScrope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    ...
}
```

The block will be scheduled on the *Android* main thread then. If you're not suspending anything within the block itself, which might be the case due to the fact that you're not using *Coroutines* right now, you might not need to worry about canceling the the `Job` being returned from `launch`.