# How do I call a method from one thread but have another thread execute the method in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's say I have a thread:

```
Thread threadA = new Thread(() -> {
    int i = doSomething();
});
```

I want to call another method that takes the int 'i' as a parameter, but doing that from threadA slows down the thread too much. How do I do this:

```
Thread threadA = new Thread(() -> {
    int i = doSomething();
    doSomethingElse(i);
});
```

but have the method 'doSomethingElse()' be executed on another thread (threadB), and if threadB is busy, wait until it's not and execute then?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170520/inter-thread-communication-in-java

Comment: I'll flag this if nobody beat me to it.

Comment: run doSomethingElse on a new thread the same way as you run doSomething in a separate thread.